# Is it appropriate to provide two different sqlSessionTemplate beans (one for BATCH sql statements)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

The question is about using MyBatis inside a spring web application. I need to execute batch sql statements (bulk insert for example) in my application. From the documentation I read about `MyBatisBatchItemWriter` class using batching features from `SqlSessionTemplate`. Activating this feature will affect the other mappers relying on it? Would it be wise to define another `SqlSessionTemplate` dedicated to BATCH statements? like in the code provided below?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd         
                  ">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<!-- 
    a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasourceref" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="${mpi.datasource.type}" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/x1v1-mybatisconfig.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="batchSqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Batch executor type may be relevant for some service and not for others.
Then it seems to be a good idea because it makes things clearer: using batch when you know why and not using them otherwise.  Because the batch effect may be puzzling: if you debug code, batched statements are not actually executed when  reaching the code row, they are jus somehow scheduled to be actually executed on next flush, either explicitly triggered or implicitly by an intermediate select statement (default behavior). Just keep in mind the behavior will last the session time and that is a distinct (isolated) session.